# Replace text not between certain tag with regex

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have the following text:

> "I want a pink banana for my dog"

And I have a list of word(s) with their definition. For example:

> "pink banana": "This is a weird banane" "banana": "This is a fruit"

I would like to replace the matching words in my sentence with something like:

```
<span tooltip="whatever">word</span>
```

That I can do, but the issue is that in my example, the first words will be replaced correctly:

```
"I want a <span tooltip="whatever">pink banana</span> for my dog"
```

But the second words will create an unwanted behavior:

```
"I want a <span tooltip="whatever">pink <span tooltip="whatever">banana</span></span> for my dog"
```

Which produce two tooltips on the word banana, which I don't want. Basically, I'd like to modify the regex used to replace the words ("\b(WORD)\b") with a regex that only replaces the word if it's not inside a "`<span tooltip="(.*)"></span>`".

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

Here's the code I use to loop through the items and replace the word:

```
foreach (var glossaryItem in items)
{
    textNode.InnerHtml = Regex.Replace(textNode.InnerHtml, $@"\b({glossaryItem.Name})\b", $"<span tooltip=\"{glossaryItem.Definition}\">$1</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: What's your current regular expression and how are you checking them in the list? Are you just looping the list and using the keys (the words) as a part of the regex check?

Comment: Yes, I edited my OP with this code.

Comment: You need to build a regex containing the alternatives of keywords. Then you may use that regex to replace with the appropriate replacement if you can map the keys to definitions.

Answer (score 2):

What you could try is replacing your regex with a negative lookahead subexpression `(?!...)` (or something similar to suit your needs).

For example:

```
foreach (var glossaryItem in items)
{
    textNode.InnerHtml = Regex.Replace(textNode.InnerHtml, $@"\b(?<!"">)({glossaryItem.Name})(?!<\/span>)\b", $"<span tooltip=\"{glossaryItem.Definition}\">$1</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

This will basically allow you to match the string, only if `">` is currently not at the beginning of the match and `</span>` is currently not at the end of the match.

Comment: Would it work if the list of word contained "pink" ? Because, once "pink banana" is replaced, there is no `pink</span>`, so it will get replaced.

Comment: The concept would be the same, you can just add another negative *lookbehind* before the `glossaryItem.Name` capture group to check for previous as well. Essentially, your problem lies in checking for anything **not** inside spans. And you can base your regex around that.

Comment: @ssougnez I just sat back down at my computer and I updated the regex for your particular case. Assuming that your tags will always end with `">` and considering the fact that I can't use non-fixed width negative lookbehind (therefore, I can't check the entire span tag), this should capture anything that's not in between the span tags you've replaced a substring with.